# sed: behavior of H and D

Tags: sed

My sed script is this:

```
# script.sed
1,3H
1,3g
3D
```

When I run it, I get the following:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -f script.sed

1

1
2
4
5
```

However, this seems wrong to me. On line 3, once the D command is executed, the pattern space has

```
1
2
3
```

When the cycle is restarted, H should set the hold space to:

```
<empty_line>
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Then, g should set the pattern space to the same content. D will then remove the first (empty) line. Every time the cycle is restarted, the hold space will effectively double. Hence, this should lead to an infinite loop.

What am I missing?

Comment: On line 3 the `D` command repeatedly deletes upto and including each line in the pattern space until no lines are left . The command essentially stays on line 3 until everything is deleted.

Comment: @potong not true. If I include a '=' before it, I can see the line number (3) getting printed multiple times. So, it starts all the way from the top.

Comment: But line 3 never gets printed because when the `D` command is executed the normal print part of the sed loop is never reached. Try inserting a `3p` command or a `3P`.

Comment: @potong I am not saying that anything would be printed. However, if sed enters an infinite loop, we could just sit there. The subsequent lines should not be printed at all.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, I believe the range command has a flip-flop behaviour and is only executed once. If the command `1,3g` is replaced by `1,2g;3g` sed should enter an infinite loop (GNU sed certainly does).

Comment: @potong you are right! wow. thanks! ... if you want, you can post your comment as an answer as well, and I can accept it. This is very tricky.

Comment: You can use comman `l` to show up pattern space in debug manner. For example `seq 5 | sed 'l;1,3H; 1,3g; l;3D'` will show you what happend.

Comment: I'm confused why `1,3g` will not cause sed entering an infinite loop while `1,2g;3g` will.

Answer (score 1):

Below, I show how I interpret the expected execution, showing as an ordered pair the result of the command, with the pattern space first and the hold space following:

```
1: H(1,\n1)  g(\n1,\n1)                                > \n1\n
2: H(2,\n1\n2) g(\n1\n2,\n1\n2)                        > \n1\n2\n
3: H(3,\n1\n2\n3) g(\n1\n2\n3,\n1\n2\n3) D(,\n1\n2\n3) >
4:                                                     > 4\n
5:                                                     > 5\n
```

If I take the output of this interpretation and concatenate it into an echo command with the `-e` option, I get:

```
$ echo -e '\n1\n\n1\n2\n4\n5\n'

1

1
2
4
5
```